# Google OAuth2 Devise Sign-in with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, oauth-2.0

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263114/google-oauth2-sign-in-with-angularjs-callback), we are using the Google javascript API to call OAuth2 ....

Next we need to sign the user in to the Rails server. Since we use Devise, I'm assume we need to call Devise, but I'm not having much luck calling Devise outside of it's usual callback controller flow.

Anyone have a template for calling Devise with the token already in hand and passing the tolken to Devise to get just a basic authorization and user sign in?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) project may be what you (and much later now, I) are looking for. It's an angular module that's designed to work with [devise token auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).